# incoherence of float point truncation and round-off in c++, vs2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, floating-point

When I test the behavior of truncation and round-off in vs2012, I found something very strange:

```
const double a = 0x3f ffff ffff ffff;
```

'a' is slightly beyond the precision of double (52 in maximum), convert 'a' back into long long type will get 0x3f ffff ffff fffe. But IEEE 754 specifies round-to-even standard for float point, so the correct number should be 0x40 0000 0000 0000.

Moreover, if a = 0x 7f ffff ffff ffff, then '(long long)a' will be 0x 80 0000 0000 0000. Different truncation behavior compared to the first example.

Then I had another try.

```
const double a = 0x3f ffff ffff fffe;
const double b = 1;
const double c = a + b;
```

This time, 'c' is 0x40 0000 0000 0000. Does anyone know why this incoherence happens?

I'm working on a geometry program, and round-off behavior is very important to the error estimation. Thanks a lot.

********************************************update 2015.7.1 *****************************************

When I tried to reproduce this problem, I realized that it might be a bug.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

using std::int64_t;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
    const int64_t big1 = 0x3fffffffffffff;
    const int64_t big2 = 0x7fffffffffffff;

    const double float1 = big1;
    const double float2 = big2;

    const int64_t *ptr1 = reinterpret_cast<const int64_t*>(&float1);
    const int64_t *ptr2 = reinterpret_cast<const int64_t*>(&float2);

    cout << std::hex;

    cout << *ptr1 << endl;
    cout << *ptr2 << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
434f ffff ffff ffff
4360 0000 0000 0000
```

The other test program is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

using std::int64_t;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
    const int64_t big [] = {
        0xfffffffffffff, 
        0x1fffffffffffff, 
        0x3fffffffffffff, 
        0x7fffffffffffff, 
        0xffffffffffffff,
    };

    const double float0 = big[0];
    const double float1 = big[1];
    const double float2 = big[2];
    const double float3 = big[3];
    const double float4 = big[4];

    const int64_t *ptr0 = reinterpret_cast<const int64_t*>(&float0);
    const int64_t *ptr1 = reinterpret_cast<const int64_t*>(&float1);
    const int64_t *ptr2 = reinterpret_cast<const int64_t*>(&float2);
    const int64_t *ptr3 = reinterpret_cast<const int64_t*>(&float3);
    const int64_t *ptr4 = reinterpret_cast<const int64_t*>(&float4);

    cout << std::hex;

    cout << *ptr0 << endl;
    cout << *ptr1 << endl;
    cout << *ptr2 << endl;
    cout << *ptr3 << endl;
    cout << *ptr4 << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
432f ffff ffff fffe
433f ffff ffff ffff
4350 0000 0000 0000
4360 0000 0000 0000
4370 0000 0000 0000
```

**These two program gives different floating point conversion for 0x3f ffff ffff ffff!**

My platform is Win8.1, Intel i5-4200. I compiled using both release and debug mode at Win32 platform and x64 platform, and got the same results. The version of my VS2012 is shown below:

[image: vs version info]

And the last question is: How can I use extended floating point? It seems that vs2012 only offer 64-bit double. Is there any longer choice?

Comment: Count your f's. 0x3 ffff ffff ffff is 50 bits.

Comment: thanks a lot, I've corrected the typo.

Comment: The last example suggests the optimizer is involved. Are you compiling with _fast_ or _strict_ FP behavior?

Comment: As described, this is definitely a bug (by which I mean a failure to conform to IEEE-754 rounding rules).  This is such a simple case, though, that this seems rather unusual (though not the most unusual behavior I've seen from VS).  Do you have a complete compilable example of the behavior?

Comment: I see 0x0040000000000000 (in VS debugger, as well as when passing it to `printf` during runtime).

Comment: you mean you cannot see the problem?@barakmanos

Comment: Not in the constellation that I've just described. But I'm working on a 64-bit platform, perhaps yours is 32-bit.

Comment: no, win32 and x64 is the same. @barakmanos

Comment: I've offer the example. Thanks. @StephenCanon

Comment: Simply looking at the assembly is so often the answer to so many questions.  But no... we couldn't do that!  I will speculate that the rounding control bits are set to extended, not double, and that the codegen here is fild, fadd in x87 in 80-bits of precision, with occasional rounding to double as the compiler decides to spill to memory.

Comment: If it is indeed using double precision, then we need to be aware that 2^54 + 1 in double is (drum roll) 2^54. Round ties to even means round down in that case.

Comment: The particular case of const int64_t big1 = 0x3fffffffffffff; -> 434f ffff ffff ffff looks like a visual studio bug to me, where it has attempted to do the conversion for you at compile time. 64-bit int -> FP conversions are broken disturbingly often.  If VS2012 has caught up to the rest of the world, you can use the %a format (e.g. 0x1.fffffffffffffp52)